# Use a PHP Function with a parameter from an HTML post form?

Tags: php

My question is this:
How do I use a php function with an argument FROM MY php/html form?

I downloaded this php function script from intechgrity.
***Link:*** **http://www.intechgrity.com/?p=808**
The **function** is: **itg_fetch_image('http://the.image.url/pic.bmp')**

What I'm doing:
1) On my website I have a php page.
2) What I did was *copy all of the intechgrity php script and pasted it into my page* (at the top, of course)

In my page I have this form, but nothing is happening.

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
<input type="text" id="Stuff" name="Stuff" maxlength="30" value="<?=$img_url;?>" />
<button type="button" onClick="newSrc();">Do it!</button>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong, how come when I hit submit the function is not working?

Comment: *"The function is: `itg_fetch_image`"* - `onClick="newSrc()` - *Hm* - Maybe if you showed us your full code perhaps.

Comment: `<?php somefunction($_POST['Stuff']); ?>`?

Comment: You need submit, instead you use js function to do something (you didn't post it there)

Comment: Also make sure short tags are enabled `<?=$img_url;?>` if not, then either enable them, or do `<?php echo $img_url;?>`

Comment: Not sure I understand the concept here... to get an image remotely, can't you just use it's url in the `src` of an html `img` tag...?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?  (I didn't check through all the code you linked to.)

```
<?php
   function itg_fetch_img($img_url, ...) {
      etc.
   }
   $img_url = $_POST['Stuff'];
   if (!empty($img_url)) itg_fetch_img($img_url, ...);
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="Stuff" name="Stuff" maxlength="30" value="<?=$img_url;?>" />
<input type="submit">Do it!</button>
</form>
```

Note that button is now an input with type submit, and javascript function is removed.